# Having trouble using phpseclib to ssh into a server

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

This is my code for `upload.php`. All my files are in the `htdocs` directory of MAMP. I can go to the url `http://localhost:8888/webpage.html` so I am assuming MAMP is working as it should. This is my code for `upload.php`.

```
<?php 
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
    include('Net/SFTP.php');
    include('Net/SSH2.php');
    //Send file via sftp to server
    echo "begin";

    echo "now connecting...";

    $connection = ssh2_connect('servername.com', 22); //server redacted
    echo "server made\n";
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password'); //username and password redacted
    echo "connected successfuly\n";

    echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
    echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

When I submit my form and it gets redirected to `upload.php`, the `upload.php` displays text saying

`begin now connecting...`

So I'm assuming it's not getting past the line

`$connection = ssh2_connect('servername.com', 22); //server redacted`

But I can't figure out why.

I am using a mac. I can ssh into the server and scp files to it via the terminal using `ssh username@servername.com` and `scp ./filename.txt username@servername.com:~/test/`. And obviously it prompts me for the password.

Maybe I have the wrong server name? Does anyone have any idea why it's not getting past that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like you're mixing the phpseclib API and the libssh2 API. Like where is the $ssh variable being defined? You set the result of ssh2_connect to $connection but then later use $ssh which has never been defined.

Anyway, try this:

```
<?php 
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
    include('Net/SFTP.php');
    include('Net/SSH2.php');
    //Send file via sftp to server
    echo "begin";

    echo "now connecting...";

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('servername.com', 22); //server redacted
    echo "server made\n";
    $ssh->login('username', 'password'); //username and password redacted
    echo "connected successfuly\n";

    echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
    echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I had been copying and pasting code from different sources but nothing was working. And my code wasn't reaching the `$ssh` variable so I wasn't concerned about it yet.  It turns out I needed instead of `. 'phpseclib'` I needed to include the entire directory path to where it was installed. And curiously it wouldn't let me include multiple things. I could include `'Net/SFTP.php'` or `'Net/SSH2.php'` but not both. Thanks.